# wso2 ESB oauthService fault handling

Tags: wso2-esb

I have a simple pass-thru API defined that includes the `oauthService` to validate an access token.  Similar to this:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="aservice" context="/aservice/v1">
    <resource methods="POST PUT GET" uri-template="/*" faultSequence="ServiceFault">
        <inSequence>
            <oauthService remoteServiceUrl="https://identityserver:9444/services/" username="admin" password="admin" description="oauth2"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint name="aservice-endpoint">
                    <address uri="http://aservice:8080/aservice/v1"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

It includes a ServiceFault sends a general message back to the client.

My question is, is it possible to have a separate fault handler that will handle validation errors from the `oauthService`?  I'd also like to handle errors from the address endpoint as well (i.e. host down, etc).  Call all of these be handled in one fault sequence definition?

I want to be able to set different HTTP response codes and headers depending on if the error is an oauth2 error or some other error type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way you can achieve it by using separate sequences. You could put the oauthService to a separate sequence which then has its own faultSequence in the tag `onError`:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="aservice" context="/aservice/v1">
<resource methods="POST PUT GET" uri-template="/*" faultSequence="ServiceFault">
    <inSequence>
        <sequence key="oauthSequence"/>
        <send>
            <endpoint name="aservice-endpoint">
                <address uri="http://aservice:8080/aservice/v1"/>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
</resource>
</api>

<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="oauthSequence" onError="myOauthFaultSequence">
   <oauthService remoteServiceUrl="https://identityserver:9444/services/" username="admin" password="admin" description="oauth2"/>
</sequence>
```

See the onError description of the Sequence: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Mediation+Sequences